# used of undeclared identifier "indexPath"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I will try to pass data between two controller using segue method but it's give me error like

> used of undeclared identifier "indexPath"

Check My Code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *index = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
        NameViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        destViewController.receiptName = [self.nameListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // here display the error.
    }
}
```

Comment: Share the code how you are calling performSegue withIdentifier..

Comment: you understand my question?@Bharath

Comment: i simply call [self.nameListArray objectAtIndex:index]; So it's work properly but always return same value on next controller

Comment: Typo: If the indexPath is assigned to `index` it's supposed to be `... objectAtIndex:index.row]`. But why not the shorter syntax `self.nameListArray[index.row]`?

Comment: @GanganiRoshan: Yes I do, and the reason for the undeclared identifier issue is address in the answer, and if you are still facing the issue you mentioned in comment after updating the variable name add in comment I will guide you what would have caused the issue.

Comment: @vadian I haven't more knowledge in this field i would start learning before few day ago. After your reply i change long syntax to short syntax Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the thrown exception the `sender` is obviously the table view cell rather than the index path.

Then you have to write

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: (UITableViewCell*)sender];
        NameViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        destViewController.receiptName = self.nameListArray[indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the variable name as follows,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
```

instead of

```
NSIndexPath *index = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
```

This would have solved the undeclared identifier issue.

Now coming to your second set of problem, 
As you mentioned in our conversation that you are not using the didSelect as per the guide you mentioned, Please **[read the documentation little in depth](https://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)** because they have mentioned to use **indexPathForSelectedRow** as below,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NameViewController *destViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        destViewController.receiptName = self.nameListArray[indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

FYI: @vadian answer is also a good way to achieve this.

Comment: After changing application will crash and show error like: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f861307

Comment: One question, how prepareForSegue is getting called is it by using "performSegue with identifier" in tableView didSelect at indexPath or you are using the segue in storyboard somehow?

Comment: why not call? and i haven't more detail about segue because i start learning ios before few day.

Comment: @GanganiRoshan: Its ok no problem, I hope you are using tableView and "didSelect" method in it right, if so please share "didSelect" that code in your question.

Comment: I guess you are not passing the "indexPath" on performSegue with identifier call and this could be the issue.

Comment: I use tableview but don't use didSelect method, any idea? how call segue method from didselect method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155648/discussion-between-bharath-and-gangani-roshan).

Answer (score 0):

Here..

```
destViewController.receiptName = [self.nameListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // here display the error.
```

You are using `indexpath` and you declare `index` so you need to change var name like...

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = (NSIndexPath *)sender;
```

and then use it as

```
destViewController.receiptName = [self.nameListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Please make sure that `sender` is kind of `NSIndexPath` or not.

Comment: After changing application will crash and show error like: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f861307